# Plugin build with C++/Juce - Crashed validation in LogicProX

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, plugins, juce

I'm completely new to this but I'm taking a course in Audio Plugin Development as a way to try and improve my understanding of C++. I've hit a wall quite early where the plugin caused Logic to crash. I'm using Xcode and Juce and when I got to this point in Xcode and built the plugin, it said 'build succeeded' and opened Logic, which then crashed, directing me back to this line of code
[thread 1: breakpoint1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLDqJ.png)

If I open Logic independently without Xcode, it's not crashing, but when I reset and rescan plugins, I get a crashed validation for that plugin
[Logic: crashed validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3OuW.png)

I don't fully understand where it's directing me to or where the problem is, I retraced my steps in following the directions in the course and I think I've done everything correctly. In the previous step I did the initial build of the plugin and that worked fine, without any crashes.
I've tried deleting breakpoints and running again but it's still the same problem. As I say, I'm very new to this so could be something very simple but any help would be great. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @ASF2021! It is difficult to help without seeing some code. Your code compiles but crashes at runtime.. A runtime error can have many causes like you could be missing some dependencies or other. If the course you are following has a forum it would be best to ask there! Otherwise pls update your post with more info.

Comment: HI @multitudes. Thanks for your reply. I tried posting on the forum but got no response. Maybe I'll try being a bit more persistent there and then come back here and post some more info if I have no luck. Thanks for your help :)